# rolling mean is not smoothing much data much

Tags: pandas, dataframe, smoothing

I am using rolling means to smooth out my data. [image: Plot]
I have seen similar posts and have tried to increase the rolling window but I do get a thin line I rather get a thick line that pretty, much covers the main data that I am trying to smooth out.

```
df_fil["OUR smooth2"]= df_fil['OUR smooth'].rolling(5000, min_periods=1).mean()

df_fil.plot(x='Time', y=['OUR','OUR smooth2'], figsize=(10,10), ylim=(0, 0.03))
```

Comment: `rolling` doesn't reduce the number of values. Use `resample` to aggregate values